# What/who is responsible for making the firefox downloads window tiny everytime?

Tags: firefox

Somehow for years on end (meaning with many different versions of firefox) whenever I want to look at the firefox downloads window, I can't find it. It then turns out that it is hidden under all the other windows on the desktop and is resized to a tiny window, see image below for a real size screenshot.

I just wonder about a few things.

1. Am I the only one with this problem?
2. What causes this? This reminds me of the time before popup blockers when minimizing/ maximizing/hiding windows was the preferred way for a lot of advertizers of making themselves unpopular. It gives me a feeling of insecurity thinking that somehow some website/virus has access to the downloads window and can thus hide/resized it. Is this a genuine concern, or is the default setting for firefox to set the downloads window to this size.

[image: Tiny downloads window]

Comment: It's certainly not the default size. Have you tried resizing it and then closing the window, then Firefox?

Comment: ok, now checked with another firefox, and it shows up normal. So it does not happen everytime. However, I know this has regularly happened to me for years, and never, EVER have I chosen to make it that small myself...

Answer (score 1):

press ctrl + j (opens up download window), resize your window and press ctrl + j again.

This should save the your window setting